# Show input range value on hover

Tags: html, input, hover, range

How can I show this input's value (on cursor position) while hovering over it? 
Hovering in middle of the input should (document append for example) value : 50...

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="0.1" style="width:100%">
```

Great example is Youtube video progress bar: (red line represents mouse position)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use MouseEvent: offsetX to get the x position, clientWidth to get input range width. Get input range max (!Important: you have to set it or else it will be 0) and caclulate the mouse position value.
Show the result using tooltip.

Pay attention it is not 100% accurate.

```js
 let x = document.getElementById('x')
    let scrubber = document.getElementById('scrubber')
    let tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip')

    function showTooltip(e) {
        let w = scrubber.clientWidth;
        let x = e.offsetX;
        let percents = x / w;
        let max = parseInt(scrubber.max)
        tooltip.innerHTML = Math.floor(percents * max + 0.5) 
    }

    window.onmousemove = function (e) {
        let x = (e.clientX + 20) + 'px';
        tooltip.style.left = x;
    }
```

```css
  #scrubber {
      width: 90%
    }
    #tooltip {
      display:none;
      position:relative;
    }
    #scrubberContainer:hover p {
      display:block;
      position:fixed;
      overflow:hidden;
    }
```

```html
    <div id='scrubberContainer'>
    <p id='tooltip'>0</p>
    <form oninput="x.value=parseInt(scrubber.value)">
    <input type="range" id="scrubber" value="50" max="100" onmousemove="showTooltip(event)" >
    <output id="x" name="x" for="a"></output>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can see the demo , it may help you..

```
<label>RATE CARD<input type="range" name="rate" id="ageInputId" min="1" max="5" oninput="ageOutputId.value = ageInputId.value"></label>
<output name="ageOutputName" id="ageOutputId">0</output>
<span>/5</span>
```

https://codepen.io/Jackmaurya/pen/GNabvV

Answer (score -1):

For simple presentation, html "title" attribute can be used.
Just like this:

```
$(".slider").change(function(){
  $(this).attr("title", $(this).val());
});
```

I'm using "slider" class to get all range inputs.